# MySQL query to give counts of results with different combinations of values

Tags: mysql

I have a table like the example below. I want to run a query to show me the total number of rows where isActive=1 AND isNew=1, isActive=1 AND isOld=1 all where customerID=1

```
orderID customerID  isActive    isNew   isOld
1       1           1           0       1
2       1           0           0       1
3       1           1           0       0
4       1           1           1       1
5       2           1           0       1
6       2           0           0       1
7       2           1           0       0
8       2           1           1       1
```

I know that I could do a query showing:

```
select count(*) from table where customer=1 and isActive=1 and isNew=1
```

But that just gives me the total of one of the conditions, I'd like to do both conditions within one query.

Something like:

```
select count1, count2 from table where (customer=1 and isActive=1 and isNew=1) as count1, (customer=1 and isActive=1 and isOld=1) as count2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the counting in the field section:

```
select sum((customer = 1) AND (isactive = 1) AND (isnew = 1)) etc...
from ...
```

MySQL will silently translate the boolean results of the `foo = bar AND baz=qux` tests into integer `0`/`1` and then sum them up.